# start second page where first page end in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some issue with the window scroll.
I created a news feed like page using angularjs with database and pagination and ng-repeat.
I want that when user click on load more button window will scroll to last position of the page 1 and then page 2 start, but I tried all option but it not working like what I want.

But it always send me last of the document.
Here is the code for reference...

```
$scope.feedCopy=function(){
    $scope.loader=false;

    $http.get('http://web.com/app/get_feeds/1/'+$scope.member_id+'?page='+$scope.feeds_current_page).then(function(response){
        $scope.feeds = $scope.feeds.concat(response.data.data);
        $scope.feeds2=angular.copy($scope.feeds);
        $current_index=$scope.feeds2[0].feed_id;

        var i=0;
        $scope.showLess=true;
        $scope.showMore=false;
            for(i;i<$scope.feeds2.length;i++)
            {
                $scope.feeds2[i].show_less=1;
                if($scope.feeds[i].feed_text!=null)
                {
                    $scope.original_length=$scope.feeds2[i].feed_text.length;

                    $scope.feeds2[i].feed_text=$scope.feeds[i].feed_text.substring(0,40);
                    $scope.temp_length=$scope.feeds2[i].feed_text.length;


                    if($scope.temp_length>=$scope.original_length)
                    {

                        $scope.feeds2[i].show_less_button=1;
                    }                       
                }
                else
                {
                    $scope.feeds2[i].show_less=-1;
                }

            }
            $scope.feeds_total_page=response.data.total_pages;
            if($scope.feeds_total_page>$scope.feeds_current_page)
            {
                $scope.feeds_current_page+=1;
                $scope.load_more=true;
            }
            $scope.feed_condition_current_page++;

    });
    $scope.iframeHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
    window.scrollTo(0,($scope.iframeHeight))

    //alert($scope.iframeHeight);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inject $window service in to your controller.

```
  $window.open("your_path/", "_blank")
```

Comment: I don't understand your suggestion, can you be more specific

Comment: I don't want to open a new window. i would like to scroll like facebook feed, when you tap to scroll new content load at the bottom. But in my case source refresh automatic and load new content and put me on the bottom